# Magento 2.3 admin not working after grunt setup

Tags: css, magento2.3, grunt

I have a big problem.I setup grunt configuration for magento 2.3 as I used to setup for magento 2.2 and renamed below files

`grunt-config.json.sample`, `package.json.sample` and `gruntfile.js.sample` by removing .sample from their name and installed node_modules through below command.

**npm install**

However When I refreshed magento admin, it's not showing any css in magento admin.

I don't know what the problem is but whenever I removed the generated package.lock.json from root admin started working as expected.

Also I created local-themes.js at `dev\tools\grunt\configs` location and added my theme name for grunt compilation purpose but admin css was not showing.

So please help.

Comment: any error found in your log file?

Comment: {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []